# I am using React for rendering some data from this api for my project but it is showing me no Access control allow origin. Any idea what's wrong?

Tags: reactjs, axios

> This is my Game.js file which I am importing in App.js. but it is not showing any data on consol.log. I am using only React js and there is no backend.
>   Instead it is showing Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.crackwatch.com/api/games' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   xhr.js:178 GET https://api.crackwatch.com/api/games net::ERR_FAILED

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
const Games=()=>{
  const [games,setGames] =useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData = async () => {
          const result = await Axios.get('https://api.crackwatch.com/api/games')
          console.log(result.data);
         let dataArray = result.data.data
      setGames (dataArray);
      };
      fetchData();
  },[]);
  return( <div>
    <h1>Most Popular Games</h1>
    <div className="live-update">
      <div className="inner">
      </div>
      <h6 className="header-6">Live Updates</h6>
      </div>
    <div className="row">
    {games.map(game =>(
        <div className="column" key={game.id}>
            <div className="card">
    <h3>{game.title}</h3>
                 <button className="learn-more">Learn More</button>
              </div>
              </div>
    ))}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
export default Games;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the APIs can only request resources from the same origin

- More Details:[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [hacking-it-out-when-cors-wont-let-you-be-great](https://medium.com/netscape/hacking-it-out-when-cors-wont-let-you-be-great-35f6206cc646)

You can use **CORS-Anywhere** to resolve the issue

- Add https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/{Your api}

**Edited Code**

```
  const Games=()=>{
  const [games,setGames] =useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData = async () => {
          const result = await Axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.crackwatch.com/api/games')
          console.log(result.data);
         let dataArray = result.data.data
      setGames (dataArray);
      };
      fetchData();
  },[]);
```

- More Details : [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/)